# ksh shell script to print and delete matched line based on a string

Tags: shell, ksh

I have 2 files like below. I need a script to find string from file2 in file1 and delete the line which contains the string from file1 and put it in another file (output1.txt). Also it shld print the lines deleted and the string if the string doesn't exist in File1 (Ouput2.txt).

File1:

```
Apple
Boy: Goes to school
Cat
```

File2:

```
Boy
Dog
```

I need output like below.

Output1.txt:

```
Apple
Cat
```

Output2.txt:

```
Dog
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: `grep -vFf File2 File1 > Output1.txt ; grep -Ff File2 File1 >Output2.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shelltre, It's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `awk` available on your system:

```
awk -v FS='[ :]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]}NR>FNR&&!($1 in a){print $1}' File2 File1 > Output1.txt
awk -v FS='[ :]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]}NR>FNR&&!($1 in a){print $1}' File1 File2 > Output2.txt
```

The script is storing in an array `a` the first element `$1` of the first file given in argument.

If the first parameter of the second file is not part of the array, print it.

Note that the delimiter is either a space or a `:`